# How to calculate the values of non-explicit function for all points of a meshgrid?

Tags: matlab

Let's say I have a function

```
f = @(x,y) g(x,y)
```

`g` is not  explicit. It should be calculated numerically after inputting `x` and `y` values.

How can I calculate and save all values of this function at points

```
[x,y] = meshgrid(0:0.1:1,0:pi/10:2*pi);
```

I call `f[x,y]`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: See [this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21804025/2586922). I think my answer to that question can be applied here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two ways to do it. Your function g should work with matrices, or you should give the values one by one

```
function eval_on_mesh()

f1 = @(x,y) g1(x,y);
f2 = @(x,y) g2(x,y);

[x,y] = meshgrid(0:0.1:1,0:pi/10:2*pi);

%# If your function work with matrices, you can do it like here
figure, surf(f1(x,y));

%# If your function doesnt, you should give the values one by one
sol = zeros(size(x));
for i=1:size(x,1)
    for j=1:size(x,2)
        sol(i,j) = f2(x(i,j),y(i,j));
    end
end
figure, surf(sol);
end

function res = g1(x, y)
res = x.^2 + y.^2;
end

function res = g2(x, y)
res = x^2 + y^2;
end
```

Comment: It depends on your function. For basic operations, usualy you can write a dot `.` in front of the operator if you want to do the operations point-wise. Without knowing your function I can not tell you anything else.

Comment: The function is a very long expression under integral2 and it seems that the expression under integral works with matrices but with integration it doesn't. Strange.