# How to calculate possible word subsequences matching a pattern?

Tags: matlab, cpu-word, sequence, distance

Suppose I have a sequence:

```
    Seq = 'hello my name'
```

and a string:

```
    Str = 'hello hello my friend, my awesome name is John, oh my god!'
```

And then I look for matches for my sequence within the string, so I get the "word" index of each match for each word of the sequence in a cell array, so the first element is a cell containing the matches for 'hello', the second element contains the matches for 'my' and the third for 'name'.

```
    Match = {[1 2];      %'hello' matches
             [3 5 11];   %'my' matches
             [7]}        %'name' matches
```

I need code to somehow get an answer saying that possible sub-sequence matches are:

```
    Answer = [1 3 7;     %[hello my name]
              1 5 7;     %[hello my name]
              2 3 7;     %[hello my name]
              2 5 7;]    %[hello my name]
```

In such a way that "Answer" contains all possible ordered sequences (that's why my(word 11) never appears in "Answer", there would have to be a "name" match after position 11.

NOTE: The length and number of matches of "Seq" may vary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the length of `Matches` may vary, you need to use [comma-separated lists](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html?s_tid=doc_12b), together with [`ndgrid`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/ndgrid.html) to generate all combinations (the approach is similar to that used in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21806668/2586922)). Then filter out combinations where the indices are not increasing, using [`diff`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/diff.html) and [logical indexing](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2013/02/20/logical-indexing-multiple-conditions/):

```
cc = cell(1,numel(Match)); %// pre-shape to be used for ndgrid output
[cc{end:-1:1}] = ndgrid(Match{end:-1:1}); %// output is a comma-separated list
cc = cellfun(@(v) v(:), cc, 'uni', 0) %// linearize each cell
combs = [cc{:}]; %// concatenate into a matrix
ind = all(diff(combs.')>0); %'// index of wanted combinations
combs = combs(ind,:); %// remove unwanted combinations
```

The desired result is in the variable `combs`. In your example,

```
combs =
     1     3     7
     1     5     7
     2     3     7
     2     5     7
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works perfectly! I didn't know the ndgrid and cellfun functions, still have to understand exactly how it works because those 2 steps aren't clear to me, but I'll investigate that on my own. Thank you, sir!

Comment: @ACenTe25 Feel free to ask if you need after you investigate :-)

Comment: I think I understand now. I could get a similar result even if I wrote `[cc{1:end}] = ndgrid(Match{1:end});` right? The only change would be the order in which combinations are delivered in `combs`, if I understand correctly.

Comment: @ACenTe25 Exactly. The only purpose of that is to get the same order as in your question. And of course you could abbreviate `[cc{1:end}] = ndgrid(Match{1:end});` to `[cc{:}] = ndgrid(Match{:});`