# Generate a matrix containing all combinations of elements from n vectors (Cartesian product)

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, combinations, cartesian-product

This question pops up quite often in one form or another (see for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21804025/2586922) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21867681/2586922)). So I thought I'd present it in a general form, and provide an answer which might serve for future reference.

> Given an arbitrary number `n` of vectors of possibly different sizes, generate an `n`-column matrix whose rows describe all combinations of elements taken from those vectors (Cartesian product) .

For example,

```
vectors = { [1 2], [3 6 9], [10 20] }
```

should give

```
combs = [ 1     3    10
          1     3    20
          1     6    10
          1     6    20
          1     9    10
          1     9    20
          2     3    10
          2     3    20
          2     6    10
          2     6    20
          2     9    10
          2     9    20 ]
```

Comment: Hey @bla, you are getting rid of quite some rep lately! :-)

Comment: I've decided to start a SO version of "The Giving Pledge", i.e. 90% of my rep is going back to the contributors , 2-3K is enough for me...

Comment: Wow! That's quite a lot of rep. But consider this: you deserve that rep as much as the other contributors. If those contributors apply that criterion, everything will be redistributed, and reditributed again, to end up more or less as in the beginning :-)

Comment: @bla Anyway, I feel very honored by the bounty. Thanks!

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The [`ndgrid`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/ndgrid.html) function almost gives the answer, but has one caveat: `n` output variables must be explicitly defined to call it. Since `n` is arbitrary, the best way is to use a [comma-separated list](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html?s_tid=doc_12b) (generated from a cell array with `n`cells) to serve as output. The resulting `n` matrices are then concatenated into the desired `n`-column matrix:

```
vectors = { [1 2], [3 6 9], [10 20] }; %// input data: cell array of vectors

n = numel(vectors); %// number of vectors
combs = cell(1,n); %// pre-define to generate comma-separated list
[combs{end:-1:1}] = ndgrid(vectors{end:-1:1}); %// the reverse order in these two
%// comma-separated lists is needed to produce the rows of the result matrix in
%// lexicographical order 
combs = cat(n+1, combs{:}); %// concat the n n-dim arrays along dimension n+1
combs = reshape(combs,[],n); %// reshape to obtain desired matrix
```

Comment: This is a nice trick indeed. It is a useful way to [generalize the Cartesian product to N dimensions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19991829/2778484). The `cat(n+1,...)` part is particularly clever. ;)

Comment: @chappjc Thanks! [In the past](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21867835/2586922) I used a call to `cellfun` to linearize the n-dim arrays prior to concatenating them, but yes, I like this better

Comment: I'm accepting my own answer because, according to my [benchmarking](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24441502/2586922), it turns out to be faster. Thanks @horchler for your answer too!

Comment: Isn't this what [`allcomb`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10064-allcomb) function does on MATLAB file exchange? (just asking).

Comment: @ParagS.Chandakkar Yes, I think it does the same (I have never used that function)

Comment: I have just done some tests with `allcomb`. I confirm it produces the same result as my answer, and in the same order. As for performance, `allcomb` seems to take only slightly more time than my solution does @ParagS.Chandakkar

Comment: Very useful. I have this as a function which can also return index combinations if given a vector of the numbers of elements instead of a cell array of the vectors themselves, like this: `if ~iscell(vectors) vectors = arrayfun(@(n) {1:n}, vectors); end`

Answer (score 27):

A little bit simpler ... if you have the Neural Network toolbox you can simply use [`combvec`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/combvec.html):

```
vectors = {[1 2], [3 6 9], [10 20]};
combs = combvec(vectors{:}).' % Use cells as arguments
```

which returns a matrix in a slightly different order:

```
combs =

     1     3    10
     2     3    10
     1     6    10
     2     6    10
     1     9    10
     2     9    10
     1     3    20
     2     3    20
     1     6    20
     2     6    20
     1     9    20
     2     9    20
```

If you want the matrix that is in the question, you can use [`sortrows`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sortrows.html):

```
combs = sortrows(combvec(vectors{:}).')
% Or equivalently as per @LuisMendo in the comments: 
% combs = fliplr(combvec(vectors{end:-1:1}).')
```

which gives

```
combs =

     1     3    10
     1     3    20
     1     6    10
     1     6    20
     1     9    10
     1     9    20
     2     3    10
     2     3    20
     2     6    10
     2     6    20
     2     9    10
     2     9    20
```

If you look at the internals of `combvec` (type `edit combvec` in the command window), you'll see that it uses different code than @LuisMendo's answer. I can't say which is more efficient overall.

If you happen to have a matrix whose rows are akin to the earlier cell array you can use:

```
vectors = [1 2;3 6;10 20];
vectors = num2cell(vectors,2);
combs = sortrows(combvec(vectors{:}).')
```

Comment: Good suggestion.  I don't have it presently, but it's good to know about.

Comment: +1 I didn't know about that function. Pity I don't have that toolbox. Maybe instead of using `sortrows` you could save time with `combs = fliplr(combvec(vectors{end:-1:1}).')` ?

Comment: @horchler I have used this quite a few times, so felt obliged for +1 :)

Answer (score 13):

I've done some benchmarking on the two proposed solutions. The benchmarking code is based on the [`timeit` function](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/18798-timeit-benchmarking-function), and is included at the end of this post.

I consider two cases: three vectors of size `n`, and three vectors of sizes `n/10`, `n` and `n*10` respectively (both cases give the same number of combinations). `n` is varied up to a maximum of `240` (I choose this value to avoid the use of virtual memory in my laptop computer).

The results are given in the following figure. The `ndgrid`-based solution is seen to consistently take less time than `combvec`. It's also interesting to note that the time taken by `combvec` varies a little less regularly in the different-size case.

[image]

---

**Benchmarking code**

Function for `ndgrid`-based solution:

```
function combs = f1(vectors)
n = numel(vectors); %// number of vectors
combs = cell(1,n); %// pre-define to generate comma-separated list
[combs{end:-1:1}] = ndgrid(vectors{end:-1:1}); %// the reverse order in these two
%// comma-separated lists is needed to produce the rows of the result matrix in
%// lexicographical order
combs = cat(n+1, combs{:}); %// concat the n n-dim arrays along dimension n+1
combs = reshape(combs,[],n);
```

Function for `combvec` solution:

```
function combs = f2(vectors)
combs = combvec(vectors{:}).';
```

Script to measure time by calling `timeit` on these functions:

```
nn = 20:20:240;
t1 = [];
t2 = [];
for n = nn;
    %//vectors = {1:n, 1:n, 1:n};
    vectors = {1:n/10, 1:n, 1:n*10};
    t = timeit(@() f1(vectors));
    t1 = [t1; t];
    t = timeit(@() f2(vectors));
    t2 = [t2; t];
end
```

Comment: I never worked with matlab, so I don't know, whether my solution in Java https://stackoverflow.com/a/10083452/312172 is adoptable to mathlab. It works without generating the cartesian product, but calculating for each given index the combination of elements, given at that index. So it can be used where speed and memory usage has to be considered. It can be adopted to long or BigInteger, well, at least for long, I should have done that. A single access is always a bit time consuming, but for random access in the range of billions, it still should work in constant time. Maybe you're interested.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a do-it-yourself method that made me giggle with delight, using `nchoosek`, although it's *not* better than @Luis Mendo's accepted solution.

For the example given, after 1,000 runs this solution took my machine on average 0.00065935 s, versus the accepted solution 0.00012877 s. For larger vectors, following @Luis Mendo's benchmarking post, this solution is consistently slower than the accepted answer. Nevertheless, I decided to post it in hopes that maybe you'll find something useful about it:

**Code:**

```
tic;
v = {[1 2], [3 6 9], [10 20]};

L = [0 cumsum(cellfun(@length,v))];
V = cell2mat(v);

J = nchoosek(1:L(end),length(v));
J(any(J>repmat(L(2:end),[size(J,1) 1]),2) | ...
  any(J<=repmat(L(1:end-1),[size(J,1) 1]),2),:)  = [];

V(J)
toc
```

gives

```
ans =

 1     3    10
 1     3    20
 1     6    10
 1     6    20
 1     9    10
 1     9    20
 2     3    10
 2     3    20
 2     6    10
 2     6    20
 2     9    10
 2     9    20

Elapsed time is 0.018434 seconds.
```

**Explanation:**

`L` gets the lengths of each vector using `cellfun`. Although `cellfun` is basically a loop, it's efficient here considering your number of vectors will have to be relatively low for this problem to even be practical.

`V` concatenates all the vectors for easy access later (this assumes you entered all your vectors as rows. v' would work for column vectors.)

`nchoosek` gets all the ways to pick `n=length(v)` elements from the total number of elements `L(end)`. **There will be more combinations here than what we need.**

```
J =

 1     2     3
 1     2     4
 1     2     5
 1     2     6
 1     2     7
 1     3     4
 1     3     5
 1     3     6
 1     3     7
 1     4     5
 1     4     6
 1     4     7
 1     5     6
 1     5     7
 1     6     7
 2     3     4
 2     3     5
 2     3     6
 2     3     7
 2     4     5
 2     4     6
 2     4     7
 2     5     6
 2     5     7
 2     6     7
 3     4     5
 3     4     6
 3     4     7
 3     5     6
 3     5     7
 3     6     7
 4     5     6
 4     5     7
 4     6     7
 5     6     7
```

Since there are only two elements in `v(1)`, we need to throw out any rows where `J(:,1)>2`. Similarly, where `J(:,2)<3`, `J(:,2)>5`, etc... Using `L` and `repmat` we can determine whether each element of `J` is in its appropriate range, and then use `any` to discard rows that have any bad element.

Finally, these aren't the actual values from `v`, just indices. `V(J)` will return the desired matrix.

Comment: It's good to have other ways to approach the problem! Just my usual comment: `'` is not transpose; `.'` is

Comment: Thanks Luis! You're right, but after second thought it is do-able with either v' or v.' since the shape of V ends up being irrelevant.

Comment: @Luis Mendo doh! I just stumbled upon [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25150027/using-transpose-versus-ctranspose-in-matlab) ... thanks for forgiving my ignorance :)

Comment: Nice Q&A you found! :-D