# How to fill an array with all possible combinations of 0 and 1?

Tags: arrays, matlab, dynamic, combinations

I have an algorith that the number of possibles combinations of 0 and 1, can reach the number 2^39. Let's say i have n=2 situations, or n1=2^2=4 combinations of 0 and 1: 00,01,10,11.From that i can create an array a=zeros(n,n1) and fill the columns with the possible combinations? That means first column has 00,second 01,third 10,last 11.I want this to be dynamic that means that n can be 1,2,3...,39, show the array will be a=zeros(n,2^n).Thanks for any response!

Comment: de2bi will convert integers to binary vectors. After knowing that it's just counting...

Comment: First of all thanks a lot.Secondly if i had searched a lit better, i wouldn't have to ask for that,because i just found that thread http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/237035, and i tested and is exactly what i want.Thank you again dave.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just for general understanding: why do you think you need an array of all combinations of all integers from 0 to 2³⁹? That array would consume 39×2³⁹/1000⁴ ≈ 21TB of RAM...last time I checked, only the world's most advanced supercomputers have such resources, and most people working with those machines consider generating arrays like this quite wasteful...

Anyway, for completeness, for any `N`, this is the simplest solution:

```
P = dec2bin(0:(2^N)-1)-'0'
```

But, a little piece of advice: `dec2bin` outputs *character arrays*. If you want *numerical arrays*, you can subtract the character `'0'`, however, that gives you an array of `doubles` according to the rules of MATLAB:

```
>> P = dec2bin(0:(2^3)-1)-'0';
>> whos P
  Name      Size            Bytes  Class     Attributes

  P         8x3               192  double
```

If you want to minimize your memory consumption, generate a logical array instead:

```
>> P = dec2bin(0:(2^3)-1)=='1';
>> whos P
  Name      Size            Bytes  Class      Attributes

  P         8x3                24  logical
```

If you want to also speed up the execution, use the standard algorithm directly:

```
%// if you like cryptic one-liners
B1 = rem(floor((0:pow2(N)-1).' * pow2(1-N:0)), 2) == 1;

%// If you like readability
B = false(N,pow2(N));
V = 0:pow2(N)-1;
for ii = 1:N
    B(ii,:) = rem(V,2)==1;
    V = (V-B(ii,:))/2;
end
```

That last one (the loop) is fastest of all solutions for any `N` (at least on R2010b and R2013a), and it has the smallest  peak memory (only 1/Nth of the cryptic one-liner).

So I'd go for that one :) 
But, that's just me.

Comment: The `ndgrid` approach (see my answer) seems to be slightly faster than your loop? At least for large `N`

Comment: @LuisMendo: I suspect that's because you generate a list of all combinations, and I convert all integers from decimal to binary. Yours is more specific to this problem, and therefore, faster. +1 though :)

Comment: @LuisMendo: I just copy-pasted and adjusted from `dec2bin`, whereas you thought a bit more :)

Comment: Actually, I copy-pasted too (from a previous [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895335/generate-a-matrix-containing-all-combinations-of-elements-taken-from-n-vectors)) :-)

Comment: Rody , i used dec2bin and worked fine. i also tested and have results for 2^20. Above that was of course impossible for the memory to return any results.

Answer (score 3):

Using [`ndgrid`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/ndgrid.html) with a [comma-separated list](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html) as output (see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895335/generate-a-matrix-containing-all-combinations-of-elements-taken-from-n-vectors)):

```
[c{1:N}] = ndgrid(logical([0 1]));
c = cat(N+1,c{N:-1:1});
c = reshape(c,[],N);
```

Example: `N=4` gives

```
c =

     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     1
     0     0     1     0
     0     0     1     1
     0     1     0     0
     0     1     0     1
     0     1     1     0
     0     1     1     1
     1     0     0     0
     1     0     0     1
     1     0     1     0
     1     0     1     1
     1     1     0     0
     1     1     0     1
     1     1     1     0
     1     1     1     1
```

Comment: Based on the resultant matrix, is there any way to dynamically calculate a element value? For example, how to know that (1,1) = 0 without mounting the matrix?

Comment: @JosuéLima The columns of row `r` are the binary expansion of `r-1`. For example, for row `3` with `4` columns the elements are `dec2bin(3-1,4)`, or `dec2bin(3-1,4)-'0'` to convert to numbers