# How do I find all permutations from a matrix with one value per column in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix, permutation

I'm fairly new to Matlab (and programming in general) and I can't figure out how to do this. Perhaps it is quite simple, but I could really use some help. I've got this matrix:

```
25    53    52    25    37
26    54     0    26    38
27    55     0    27     0
28    56     0    28     0
 0    59     0     0     0
 0    60     0     0     0
```

I would like to compute all different combinations, in terms of rows with one value from each column, like, 25,53,52,25,37 and 25,54,52,26,38 and 25,54,52,27,0 etc. Besides, I want to discard the combinations containing 0 (like 25,53,0,25,37).

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this [function](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/38310-deep-learning-toolbox/content/rasmusbergpalm-DeepLearnToolbox-45ef96c/util/allcomb.m), `allcombo([25:28],[53:56 59:60],52,[25:28],[37:38])` should be what you are looking for.

Comment: This would certainly what I want! But, unfortunately Matlab does not seem to recognize it? 
>> allcombo([25:28],[53:60],52,[25:28],[37:38])
Undefined function 'allcombo' for input arguments of type 'double'.

Comment: I linked a function of the matlab file exchange. It's a portal where matlab users upload functions for other matlab users, you have to download it and put it to your search path.

Comment: +1 Kool tool that one! Edited the code for some correction, hope that was okay.

Answer (score 0):

Adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21895344/2586922):

```
M = [ 25    53    52    25    37
       26    54     0    26    38
       27    55     0    27     0
       28    56     0    28     0
        0    59     0     0     0
        0    60     0     0     0 ]; %// data matrix

[m n] = size(M);
C = mat2cell(M, m, ones(1,n)); %// convert to cell array of column vectors
combs = cell(1,n); %// pre-define to generate comma-separated list
[combs{end:-1:1}] = ndgrid(C{end:-1:1}); %// the reverse order in these two
%// comma-separated lists is needed to produce the rows of the result matrix in
%// lexicographical order 
combs = cat(n+1, combs{:}); %// concat the n n-dim arrays along dimension n+1
combs = reshape(combs,[],n); %// result: each row gives a combination
```

This gives, in your example:

```
>> combs(1:5,:)
ans =
    25    53    52    25    37
    25    53    52    25    38
    25    53    52    25     0
    25    53    52    25     0
    . . .
```

If any column has repeated entries, the result will have repeated rows. To keep only unique rows (note this changes the order of the rows):

```
combs = unique(combs,'rows');
```