# HeatMap with RGB in Matlab

Tags: matlab, colors, visualization, rgb, heatmap

I want to create a random value from *HeatMap* in my project, I'v *RGB* vector of `1x3`, What approach should be appropriate for me for selecting random color, However I created following *RGB's* colors vector, by what condition I can create a sample of *HeatMap* using *RGB's*, I currently need *10 to 15* colors only. What would be the suggestions to create *HeatMap* scenario in *Matlab*.

```
Red = [1 0 0]
Yellow = [1 1 0]
Green = [0 0.5 0]
Cyan = [0 0.5 0.5]
Blue = [0 0 1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [**`allcomb`**](http://www.mathworks.in/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10064-allcomb) to generate all possible combinations and then select 15 random ones from it -

**Code**

```
list_all_colors = allcomb([0 0.5 1],[0 0.5 1],[0 0.5 1])

num_rand_colors = 15 %%// Number of colors needed
rand_colors = list_all_colors(randi(size(list_all_colors,1),num_rand_colors,1),:)
```

If you don't want to use `allcomb` and have Neural Network Toolbox, you may use [**`combvec`**](http://www.mathworks.in/help/nnet/ref/combvec.html), like this to generate all such combinations (code snippet from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895335/generate-a-matrix-containing-all-combinations-of-elements-taken-from-n-vectors) ) -

```
vectors = {[0 0.5 1], [0 0.5 1], [0 0.5 1]}
list_all_colors = combvec(vectors{:})'
```

Comment: all combinations may full fill the HeatMap phenonmena, i.e light blue,blue and dark blue type color combinations? I think it may contain duplicates or irrelevant colors.

Comment: @AhsanAli You were right! Check out **Edit 1**. One thing I would like to add to it is that you can have more colors to choose from if you let something like `0.25` or `0.75` come into the input vectors.

Comment: it gives me error of, Undefined function 'allcomb' for input arguments of type 'double'.

Comment: You need to get `allcomb` function from [here](http://www.mathworks.in/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10064-allcomb) or use `combvec` approach mentioned in the solution. Fixed in **Edit 1**. Hope it works!

Comment: Yeah it works, but gives 15x27 matrix of random colors having redundant values.

Comment: Think you missed that very important transpose sign `'` at the end of `list_all_colors = combvec(vectors{:})'`.