# Sorting matrix diagonal wise and indexes are given as rank using matlab

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matrix, normalize, ordinal

This first matrix table1 contains normalized values for 5 names.I need to perform some operations on this matrix and I have to obtain second matrix as shown in table2.

Diagonal elements of table2 should obtained by giving rank(ordinal value) to each value.That means highest element is given 5th rank and next 4th 3rd and so on.

Remaining elements of table  obtained by giving rank to each value starting from 4 because only  4 elements remaining. Because already we are given rank to diagonal elements.Zero should be kept as it is.Suppose take table1 as A matrix and table2 as B matrix.

OPERATION1:For diagonal elements

```
   B(1,1)=5(first largest element)
   B(2,2)=1(5th largest element)
   B(3,3)=4(4th largest element)
   B(4,4)=2(2nd largest element)
   B(5,5)=3(3rd largest element)
```

OPERATION2:For remaining elements

```
      B(1,2)=3(2nd largest element)
      B(1,3)=4(1st  largest element)
      B(1,4)=1(4th largest element)
      B(1,5)=2(3rd largest element)
```

And so on..

```
        Table1:
                                  BASAVARAJ   MANOJ      NATESH       VIJAY    GOWDA

           BASAVARAJ            1.0000    0.2727      0.3182     0.0455    0.2727

               MANOJ            0.2727   0.2727         0            0         0

              NATESH            0.3182     0          0.4545     0.1818        0

               VIJAY            0.0455     0          0.1818     0.2727     0.0909

               GOWDA            0.2727     0              0     0.0909    0.3636




   Table2:




                             BASAVARAJ    MANOJ      NATESH    VIJAY  GOWDA



  BASAVARAJ                      5         3       4        1       2
     MANOJ                       4         1       0        0       0
     NATESH                      4         0       4        3       0
     VIJAY                       2         0       4        2       3
     GOWDA                       4         0       0        3       3
```

Comment: How is this different from this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23234608/matlab-code-for-given-matrix-using-for-loop-by-adding-rows-and-finding-minimum-v

Comment: In this we have to calculate ordinal values depending upon their maximum values.For diagonal elements there will be 5 ranks.Remaining elements there wil be 4 ranks and 0 will remains same.

Comment: Anybody give some idea

Comment: It might be a good idea to go back to your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23234608/matlab-code-for-given-matrix-using-for-loop-by-adding-rows-and-finding-minimum-v) and either accept the answer if it solves your problem, or provide feedback as to why it doesn't.