# generating a matrix with all possibilities in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, combn

is there a simple command to do this:

```
M = 0 0 0
    0 0 1
    0 1 0
    0 1 1
    1 0 0
    1 0 1
    1 1 0
    1 1 1
```

i found this http://www.mathworks.co.kr/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7147-combn--4-3- but this isn't yet a thing in matlab

tried `M = combn([0 1],3)` bo i got  `Undefined function 'combn' for input arguments of type 'double'. in return`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy approach is to generate all numbers from `0` to `2^n-1`, where `n` is the number of rows, and convert them into binary:

```
n = 3;
result = dec2bin(0:2^n-1)-'0';
```

Or particularize [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21895335/2586922) to your case.

Comment: how would i remove the eye(I) vectores(one 1 in a line) and store the rest?

Comment: @user2202368 Sorry, I don't understand your question

Comment: @LuisMendo from the matrix of all combination i would like the remove lines(1 0 0 0; 0 1 0 0; 0 0 1 0; 0 0 0 1) and save what is left

Comment: @user2202368 Oh I see. Use `result2 = result(sum(result,2)~=1,:);` (this keeps only rows whose sum is different than 1)

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for matlab's `perms()` function.

```
v0=[0 0 0]; 
v1=[1 0 0];
v2=[1 1 0];
v3=[1 1 1]; 
p1=perms(v1);
p2=perms(v2);
combs = cat(1,v0,p1,p2,v3);
```

This of course gives all permutations meaning that order matters (even for the zeros) so to get only the unique combinations you could then use:

```
combs=unique(combs,'rows');
```

Which gives:

```
combs =
     0     0     0
     0     0     1
     0     1     0
     0     1     1
     1     0     0
     1     0     1
     1     1     0
     1     1     1
```

As a side note if you downloaded the file from the file exchange make sure it is on your matlab path, or in your current directory and this will avoid the unknown function error. You can read about how matlab's path works [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/path.html)

Comment: Why was this downvoted? Please comment on how I can improve the answer.