# Fast algorithm to get dispositions and combinations in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I need to adjust the following algorithm in Matlab, in particular I refer to the part for the construction of `B` because it takes to much time when `n` is large. The part for the construction of `A` has been brilliantly suggested here [Fast algorithm to get combinations in Matlab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23505086/fast-algorithm-to-get-combinations-in-matlab)

```
clear all
%% Construction of A: list of COMBINATIONS of the elements of the set {0,1} in n-1 places (organize
% 2 elements in n-1 places with repetitions and the order does NOT matter) repeated twice:
% once when the n-th element is 1, the other when the n-th element is 0. 

n=3; 

A=zeros(n,2*n);
A(:,1)=1;
for i=2:2:n*2-1
    A(:,i-1)=circshift(A(:,i-1),[-1 0]);
    A(:,i)=A(:,i-1);
    A(end,i)=0;
    A(:,i+1)=A(:,i);
end
A(:,end-1)=circshift(A(:,end-1),[-1 0]);
A=A';
groupindex=(linspace(1,size(A,1),size(A,1)))'; 
A=[A groupindex];

%% Construction of B: for each row of A -excluding the last column- (for example consider row 1 of A: 1 1 1) I want to 
%                     (step 1) List all possible DISPOSITIONS of the elements of
%                              the set {0,1} in n-1 places
%                     (step 2) Combine row 1 with all
%                              possible dispositions listed in step 1 and
%                              get C=[1 1 1 1 1; 1 1 1 1 0; 1 1 1 0 1; 1 1 1 0 0]
%                     (step 3) Associate with the same number some rows of C according to this logic: 
%                              [1 1 1 1 1]: the first two elements are ones; the third element is 1; the first two elements should be associated 
%                                         with the fourth and the fifth elements which are
%                                         ones; so 1 1 1 1 can be represented as (1,1), (1,1) 1
%                              [1 1 1 1 0]: (1,1), (1,0), 1
%                              [1 1 1 0 1]: (1,0), (1,1), 1
%                              [1 1 1 0 0]: (1,0), (1,0), 1
%                              So row 2 and row 3 of C are equivalent
%                              if we exchange (1,0) and (0,1) and should
%                              be associated with the same number 
%
%                     Consider now instead row 3 of A: 1 0 1 
%                     (step 1) ...
%                     (step 2) C=[1 0 1 1 1; 1 0 1 1 0; 1 0 1 0 1; 1 0 1 0 0]
%                     (step 3) [1 0 1 1 1]: (1,1), (0,1) 1
%                              [1 0 1 1 0]: (1,1), (0,0) 1
%                              [1 0 1 0 1]: (1,0), (0,1) 1
%                              [1 0 1 0 0]: (1,0), (0,0) 1
%                              So there are no equivalent rows



%(step 1)
g=makeindex(n-1);   %matrix 2^(n-1)x(n-1): list of dispositions of the elements of the set {0,1} in n-1 places 

%(step 2)
repA=kron(A, ones(2^(n-1),1)); %repeat each row of A 2^(n-1) times

repg=repmat(g,size(A,1),1);  %stack vertically the matrix g for size(A,1) times

B=[repA(:,1:n) repg repA(:,n+1)];   %matrix size(A,1)*2^(n-1) x  (n+n-1+1)

%(step 3)
Xr=B(:,n); 

m=sum(B(:,1:n-1),2); 

lm=zeros(size(B,1),1);
for i=1:size(B,1)
 count=0;
 for j=1:n-1
     if B(i,j)==1 && B(i,n+j)==1
         lm(i)=count+1;   
         count=lm(i);
     end
 end
end

lf=zeros(size(B,1),1);
for i=1:size(B,1)
 count=0;
 for j=1:n-1
     if B(i,j)==0 && B(i,n+j)==1
         lf(i)=count+1;  
         count=lf(i);
     end
 end
end


classindex=zeros(size(B,1),1);   
count=0;

for i=1:size(B,1)
    old=classindex;
    for j=1:size(B,1)
        if j>=i && lm(i)==lm(j) && lf(i)==lf(j) && Xr(i)==Xr(j) && m(i)==m(j) && classindex(j)==0
                classindex(j)=count+1;  
        end
    end
    diff=old-classindex;
    if any(diff)==1;
        count=count+1;
    end    

end
```

The function makeindex is

```
function [index]=makeindex(k)                                              %
                                                                           %
total=2^k;                                                                 %
index=zeros(total,k);                                                      %
i=1;                                                                       %
for i=1:k                                                                  %
    ii=1;                                                                  %
    cc=1;                                                                  %
    c=total/(2^i);                                                         %
    while ii<=total                                                        %
        if cc <=c                                                          %
            index(ii,i)=1;                                                 %
            cc=cc+1;                                                       %
            ii=ii+1;                                                       %
        else                                                               %
            ii=ii+c;                                                       %
            cc=1;                                                          %
        end                                                                %
    end                                                                    %
end                                                                        %
                                                                           %
end
```

Comment: I can see a pattern there again. Maybe you can try and figure it out by yourself first. Right now, I don't have time.

Comment: I tried but I can't see anything.

Comment: There are only equals in each section. Equals defined by Matrix from Step 2 (B(:,end)). 
Every following section has the same pattern as the one before (1 + 2 have the same pattern, 3 + 4 have the same pattern, 4+5 have the same...).

Answer (score 0):

After some puzzling I came up with that:

```
function B=fast_matrix(n)

B = zeros([2^n*n,2*n]);

B(1:2:end,end-1)=1;
for i = 1:n
    for k=1:2^(i-1)
    B(k:2^(i):end,end-i)=1;
    end
end

for i = 1:n-1
    B(1:(2^n*(n-i)),i)=1;
end

step = 2^n/2;
for i = 1:2*n
    B((i-1)*step+1:i*step,end)=i;
end

end
```

Time check:

```
tic;
A = fast_matrix(15);
toc;
Elapsed time is 0.113626 seconds.
```

Comment: It's not exactly what I want. There should be an additional row with numbers following the logic I have illustrated above. You can see it from the output of my code.

Comment: Ah sorry. Didn't see the full sketch.