# Unique (finite length) combinations of a given set of elements - Implementation in Matlab

Tags: matlab, combinations

I have the following problem. I need to reproduce all the unique combinations of 0s and 1s that include exactly m zeros and exactly n ones. For example if I have 2 zeros and 3 ones the combinations I am looking for are the 10 following:

1)  0   0   1   1   1

2)  0   1   0   1   1

3)  0   1   1   0   1

4)  0   1   1   1   0

5)  1   0   0   1   1

6)  1   0   1   0   1

7)  1   0   1   1   0

8)  1   1   0   0   1

9)  1   1   0   1   0

10) 1   1   1   0   0

Right now, I am using A=perms([0 0 1 1 1]) and then unique(A,'rows') but this is really time consuming if the length of the vector is more than 10. Can anybody think of a more efficient solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Approach 1**:

1. Generate all "combinations" of `m+n` elements taken from the set `[0 1]`. This can be done efficiently using [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895335/generate-a-matrix-containing-all-combinations-of-elements-taken-from-n-vectors).
2. Keep only those combinations that contain `n` ones.

Code:

```
m = 7; %// number of zeros
n = 9; %// number of ones
L = m+n;
vectors = repmat({[0 1]}, 1, L);
combs = cell(1,L);
[combs{end:-1:1}] = ndgrid(vectors{end:-1:1});
combs = cat(L+1, combs{:});
combs = reshape(combs,[],L);
combs = combs(sum(combs,2)==n,:);
```

Example result for `m=2; n=3`:

```
combs =
     0     0     1     1     1
     0     1     0     1     1
     0     1     1     0     1
     0     1     1     1     0
     1     0     0     1     1
     1     0     1     0     1
     1     0     1     1     0
     1     1     0     0     1
     1     1     0     1     0
     1     1     1     0     0
```

**Approach 1 modified**

To save memory, use `uint8` values in step 1, and convert to `double` at the end of step 2:

```
m = 7; %// number of zeros
n = 9; %// number of ones
L = m+n;
vectors = repmat({uint8([0 1])}, 1, L);
combs = cell(1,L);
[combs{end:-1:1}] = ndgrid(vectors{end:-1:1});
combs = cat(L+1, combs{:});
combs = reshape(combs,[],L);
combs = double(combs(sum(combs,2)==n,:));
```

**Approach 2**:

Similar to approach 1, but in step 1 generate all combinations as binary expressions of all integers from `0` to `2^(m+n)-1`, using [`dec2bin`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dec2bin.html). This produces a `char` array, so it should be as memory-efficient as approach 1 modified. Then, step 2 should be slightly adapted to use `char`s, and a final conversion to numeric values is required:

```
m = 7; %// number of zeros
n = 9; %// number of ones
combs = dec2bin(0:2^(m+n)-1);
combs = combs(sum(combs=='1',2)==n,:)-'0';
```