# Matlab : create parameter table from parameters for sweep analysis

Tags: matlab, loops, nested

I am currently modelling the resistive response of a material upon stretching it. I have about 10 parameters, and I would like to make a sweep study on some of them, sometimes sweeping 1, 2, or maybe 4 (etc.) parameters without having to modify my code too much.

MWE:

The study function

```
function result = mystudy(a,b,c,d,e)
         result = a+b+c+d+e
end
```

The main

```
%study of the electric response of a material.
%parameters:
a = 3;
b = 5;
c = 11:13;  %sweeping c 
d = 0:1;    %sweeping d too
e = 25;


%code needed to achieve the following table:
parameter_table = 
3 5 11 0 25
3 5 11 1 25
3 5 12 0 25
3 5 12 1 25
3 5 13 0 25
3 5 13 1 25


for num_study = 1:size(parameter_table,1)

    parameters = { parameter_table(num_study,:) };
    result = mystudy( parameters{:} );
end
```

The clear advantages of proceeding this way :

- I always have only 1 loop and don't need to nest-loop my study depending on how many parameters I want to sweep.
- It should be possible to launch a new study my simply modifying the entries under %parameters:

My only difficulty is to create the parameter_table, where each line is the set of parameters that will be used. Is there a smart way to make the table ?

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21895335/2586922) what you want?

Comment: Hi Luis,

Yes it is exactly that. Thank you.

Comment: Closing as duplicate then