# Matlab creating a design of experiment list

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a range of conditions I want to run through a Matlab code,

```
Var1 = {'A1', 'B1'};
Var2 = {'A2', 'B2', 'C2', 'D2'};
Var3 = {2.5, 3, 3.5, 4, 4.5};
Var4 = {2E-6, 5E-6, 10E-6, 0.25E-3, 0.5E-3, 1E-3, 2E-3};
Var5 = {5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 125, 150, 200};
```

Is there an easy way I can create a matrix (or cell array) that has all the 2*4*5*7*16 combinations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result needs to be a cell array, because a matrix can't contain numbers and strings simultaneously.

This [question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895335/generate-a-matrix-containing-all-combinations-of-elements-taken-from-n-vectors) achieve what you want but with vector inputs (as opposed to cell array inputs). So you can

1. Transform each of your input variables into a numeric vector, to be used as index;
2. Generate all combinations;
3. Convert back by indexing.

Code:

```
%// Step 1:
vectors = {1:numel(Var1), 1:numel(Var2), 1:numel(Var3), 1:numel(Var4), 1:numel(Var5)};
%// Step 2:
n = numel(vectors);
combs = cell(1,n);
[combs{end:-1:1}] = ndgrid(vectors{end:-1:1});
combs = cat(n+1, combs{:});
combs = reshape(combs,[],n);
%// Step 3:
result = [Var1(combs(:,1)).' Var2(combs(:,2)).' Var3(combs(:,3)).' ...
    Var4(combs(:,4)).' Var5(combs(:,5)).'];
```

In your example, this produces the following 4480x5 cell array:

```
result = 
    'A1'    'A2'    [2.5000]    [2.0000e-006]    [  5]
    'A1'    'A2'    [2.5000]    [2.0000e-006]    [ 10]
    'A1'    'A2'    [2.5000]    [2.0000e-006]    [ 15]
        ...
    'B1'    'D2'    [4.5000]    [     0.0020]    [150]
    'B1'    'D2'    [4.5000]    [     0.0020]    [200]
```