# Cartesian product of sets in Scilab

Tags: matlab, vector, set, scilab, cartesian-product

I've been looking for a fucntion that is building Cartesian product of given sets, just like this:

```
Example: A = [-1 -3 -5]; B = [10 11]; C = [0 1]; 

X = SETPROD(A,B,C) 
X = 

  -5 10 0 
  -3 10 0 
  -1 10 0 
  -5 11 0 
  -3 11 0 
  -1 11 0 
  -5 10 1 
  -3 10 1 
  -1 10 1 
  -5 11 1 
  -3 11 1 
  -1 11 1
```

Actually I was able to find such function for Matlab http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/5898-setprod
but unfortunately that doesn't work in Scilab.

I know this problem is pretty straightforward, but this is my first program that I'm doing in Scilab. Thank you!

Comment: This MATLAB post may help you.  You may be able to transfer it over using SciLab: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895335/generate-a-matrix-containing-all-combinations-of-elements-taken-from-n-vectors

Comment: Scilab has an `ndgrid` function, so that should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the number of factors in the product (for example, you will be multiplying 3 sets), then `ndgrid` does everything for you:

```
A = [-1 -3 -5]
B = [10 11]
C = [0 1]
[X, Y, Z] = ndgrid(A, B, C)
P = [X(:) Y(:) Z(:)]
```

where the matrix P lists the elements of the products in the form you want.

---

For a variable number of factors,  [MATLAB approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895335/) does not seem to work (or I could not figure out how to pass a variable number of arguments to `ndgrid` in Scilab). Instead, I looked up the [source of ndgrid](http://cgit.scilab.org/cgit.cgi/scilab/plain/scilab/modules/elementary_functions/macros/ndgrid.sci) and followed its logic.

```
 // input is a cell array of row vectors

c = cell()
n = // number of vectors
for k=1:n
  c(k).entries = // your k-th vector
end

 // Here the code that receives the cell array c and finds the product

n = length(c)
dim = zeros(1,n)

for k=1:n
  dim(k) = length(c(k).entries)
end

P = zeros(prod(dim),n)

for k=1:n
  f1 = ones(1,prod(dim(k+1:$)))
  f2 = ones(1,prod(dim(1:k-1)))
  P(:,k) = (f1.*.(c(k).entries).*.f2)'
end
```

Again, P has the elements of the product, one in each row. Note that `.*.` is not a typo: it's the Kronecker product of vectors. For example,

```
[1 2 3].*.[1 1] = [1 1 2 2 3 3]
[1 1].*.[1 2 3] = [1 2 3 1 2 3]
```

Kronecker product with 1-vectors `f1` and `f2` ensures that the entries are repeated in the correct pattern to produce all product elements. Swapping `f1` and `f2` results in a different ordering of elements, which may be more to your liking.

Comment: Hi, what's the meaning of $ in Scilab?

Comment: It's like `end` in Matlab. The index of the last element of array. If x is an array, x($) is its last element.