# Matlab: how to build a combination according to the logical 0 and 1 but by adding 100?

Tags: matlab, combinations

From the vector `V=[3 31 40]`, how to find the following combination:

```
   3    31    40
   3    31   140
   3   131    40
   3   131   140
 103    31    40
 103    31   140
 103   131    40
 103   131   140
```

the construction is done by following the logic of the combination of `0` and `1`, but by adding `100`

Comment: Use [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895335/generate-a-matrix-containing-all-combinations-of-elements-taken-from-n-vectors) with `vectors = { [3 103], [31 131], [40 140] };`. Let me know if that fully serves your needs, so that I can close as duplicate

Comment: Or, since this is the binary case, you can use the simpler `combs = bsxfun(@plus, 100*(dec2bin(0:2^numel(V)-1)-'0'), V)`

Answer (score 1):

Using this:

```
V=[3 31 40] ;

comb = dec2bin((0:2^numel(V)-1).') ;   %'// generate all the possible binary combinations
cl   = logical( double(comb)-48 )  ;   %// translate them to an array of logical
Vout = repmat( V , size(cl,1),1 ) + cl.*100  ; %// replicate the initial array and add `100` when relevant
```

Will give you:

```
Vout =
     3    31    40
     3    31   140
     3   131    40
     3   131   140
   103    31    40
   103    31   140
   103   131    40
   103   131   140
```

You can compact it in one line if you want:

```
Vout = repmat( V , size(cl,1),1 ) + (double(dec2bin((0:2^numel(V)-1).'))-48).*100  ;
```

Comment: missing the first line!