# Computing all N-bit strings in matlab through inbuilt command

Tags: algorithm, matlab, set, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Given a set `S=[a,b,c,v,f,d,e]`, we want to enumerate each possible non-empty subsets. Clearly there will be `2^7-1` such subsets. There ia a way of computing the subsets explicitly like this:-

[image]

One could map the above set `S` to a 7-bit string and then compute all possible 7-bit strings using the pseudo code above implemented in matlab. Each will correspond to a desired subset except the first one. Above pic is from lec. slides of Computer Science 226: Algorithms and Data Structures for Spring 2011.

I am looking for a MATLAB command that does this automatically. Otherwise what is the easiest way to enumerate all non-empty subsets in matlab with least coding required?

Comment: `dec2bin([1:2^7-1].')`?

Comment: Actually, you don't even need the transpose. `dec2bin(1:2^7-1)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Matlab: how to build a combination according to the logical 0 and 1 but by adding 100?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27825298/matlab-how-to-build-a-combination-according-to-the-logical-0-and-1-but-by-addin)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure how efficient it is, but it's super short:

```
combMat = (dec2bin(1:(2.^numel(S)-1)) == '1');
```

And each row is a logical index into `S` to create a set.