# matlab find similar values in a row of a cell array

Tags: matlab, similarity

I gather my result into a cell array. How can I find similar values in each row?

For example, I want to find that `ex{6,1}`, `ex{6,2}` and `ex{6,3}` have same values in my ex cell array.

Comment: I think this might be a duplicate of [Generate a matrix containing all combinations of elements taken from n vectors](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21895335/2545927)

Comment: So for one row of your cell array, you want to determine which values are similar?  Don't you need some sort of reference?  Do you use the first element of the row as a reference point, and determining how many elements are the same?  Do you want to return **all** combinations of column elements that contain one value?  kkuilla's possible duplicate may be correct in this matter.