# How can I fill a matrix with all the N-Ary numbers fast?

Tags: performance, matlab, matrix

It is really stupid all I am trying to do is having a 7 column matrix consisiting all mod 7 numbers and it takes a huge time to generate such a matrix utilizing the following code

```
to = 7^k;
msgValue = zeros(to,k);
for l=0:to
    for kCounter=0:(k-1)
        msgValue(l+1,kCounter+1)=mod((l/7^kCounter),7);
    end 
end
msgValue = floor(msgValue);
```

How can I do this faster?

Comment: How about `dec2base`?

Comment: In addition to the very good answers you got, you could also take [this route](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895335/generate-a-matrix-containing-all-combinations-of-elements-taken-from-n-vectors). It should be pretty fast too.

Comment: @LuisMendo, when I saw this question I directly went to your `comb` solution to see if it would work for that. It's only when I started to rework your input cell array that I realized that a simple matrix multiplication could do the job directly. I should have mentioned your post anyway, its so often useful that it is good to have references to it.

Comment: @Hoki Yes, matrix multiplcation is always a fast approach, when possible. My answer is more general, but is probably slower in this case. Thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or another vectorized approach (direct matrix multiplication):

```
msgValue = floor( mod( (0:7^k).' * (1./(7.^(0:k-1))),7 ) ) ;
```

a wee bit faster than the famous `bsxfun` ;-)

```
%// For 10000 iterations, k=3
Elapsed time is 2.280774 seconds. %// double loop
Elapsed time is 1.329179 seconds. %// bsxfun
Elapsed time is 0.958945 seconds. %// matrix multiplication
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [`vectorized approach`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html) with [`bsxfun`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) -

```
msgValue = floor(mod(bsxfun(@rdivide,[0:to]',7.^(0:(k-1))),7));
```

**Quick runtime tests for `k = 7`:**

```
-------------------- With Original Approach
Elapsed time is 1.519023 seconds.
-------------------- With Proposed Approach
Elapsed time is 0.279547 seconds.
```

Comment: nice use of `bsxfun`, but unnecessary in this case you can do without.

Answer (score 0):

I used a submssion from matlab central called [rude](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/6436-rude--a-pedestrian-run-length-decoder-encoder), which I tend to use from time to time and was able to eliminate one for loop and vectorize the code to some extent.

```
tic
k=7;
modval = 7;
to=modval^k;
mods = mod(0:(modval-1),modval);
msgValue=zeros(to,k);
for kCounter=1:k
    aux = rude(modval^(kCounter-1)*ones(1,modval),mods)';
    msgValue(:,kCounter) = repmat(aux,to/(7^kCounter),1);
end
toc
```

The idea behind the code is to make at the beginning of each iteration the building block of the column vector using the rude function. Rude, in turn, uses mods = [0 1 2 3 4 5 6] as a starting point for the manipulation. The real work is done through vectorization.

You did not mention how long your code takes to run. So I timed it just once to give you a rough idea.  It ran in 0.43 seconds in my machine, a Windows 7 Ultimate, 2.4 GHz, 4GB Ram, Dual CPU.

Also, the way you defined your loop adds a repetition in your msgValue matrix. The first row consists of zero values throughout all columns, and so the last row, which I also fixed. For a toy example with k=3, your code returns a 344x1 matrix, while you explicitly initialize it as a 7³x1 (343x1) matrix.