# Matlab: Reshaping grid points from ndgrid into N x m matrix

Tags: arrays, matlab, multidimensional-array

I would like to enumerate grid points in a `N x m` matrix, where `N` is the number of grid points and `m` is the number of dimensions in the grid. For a 2D grid (i.e., `m=2`), this I can accomplish this with:

```
a = -1:1;
b = -2:2;
[A,B] = meshgrid(a,b);
c=cat(2,A',B');
d=reshape(c,[],2);
d
```

where `d` is a `15 x 2` matrix.

How do I to this in higher dimensions after generating the grid points with `ndgrid`? For example:

```
[A, B, C] = ndgrid(-1:1, -2:2, 0:3);
```

In this example, I want to convert the elements of `A,B,C` to a `60 x 3` matrix.

Comment: Placing points into a 2-column matrix inherently means that each row is a 2D point.  Using `ndgrid` in your second case provides 3D points.  Do you mean a `60 x 3` matrix, not `60 x 2`?  You have an extra degree of freedom when calling `ndgrid` with three vectors as you will produce 3D points... so where does the loss of dimension (3D -> 2D) go?  For the sake of understanding you better, please provide a physical example given input points and what the expected output `N x 2` matrix looks like.

Comment: Realized this mistake immediately after posting and just edited. I meant a `60 x 3` matrix.

Comment: Is `d=[A(:) B(:) C(:)]` what you want? Anyway, the problem with that is you need to rewrite the code if the number of dimensions varies. For a more general approach that avoids that see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895335/generate-a-matrix-containing-all-combinations-of-elements-taken-from-n-vectors)

Comment: @LuisMendo - I think that merits marking as a duplicate.