# how to easily apply quadratic augmentation in matlab

Tags: matlab

Is there a quick and easy method of taking some vector `[x,y,z]` and generating `[xx,xy,xz,yy,yz,zz]` ?

`nchoosek` is going to omit the squared terms. I can manually adding them... Just wondering if there's a better solution

Comment: What is `xx`? Are you not missing a `*` sign here? Also, what are `x`, `y`, `z`? Scalars or matrices? That's important to consider because multiplication may not be commutative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the vector consists only of single elements, one way I can suggest is to use a combination of [`find`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) and [`triu`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/triu.html).  Given that your vector is stored in the variable `A`, try:

```
[X,Y] = find(triu(ones(numel(A))));
P = A(X).*A(Y);
```

`triu` extracts out the upper triangular portion of the matrix.  By extracting out the upper triangular portion of a matrix entirely of ones, we can use `find` to determine the row and column locations of the non-zero entries.  Each row and column location corresponds to a pair of locations in your vector that you would multiply together to achieve your desired result.  The row and column locations would be stored in `X` and `Y` respectively which you would then use to access the vector `A` and element-wise multiply to achieve the desired result.

Comment: You answered, but what if `x,y,z` were each column vectors themselves?

Comment: @2c2c I assumed in your post that the elements `x` `y` and `z` were all single elements.  If you desire that these are column vectors instead, have a look at this canonical post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895335/generate-a-matrix-containing-all-combinations-of-elements-taken-from-n-vectors/21895344#21895344