# Cartesian product of row-indices in Matlab

Tags: matlab, cartesian-product

I have a binary matrix `A` of dimension `mxn` with `m>n` in Matlab. I want to construct a matrix `B` of dimension `cxn` listing row wise each element of the Cartesian product of the row indices of the ones contained in `A`. To be more clear consider the following example.

Example:

```
  %m=4;
  %n=3;

  A=[1 0 1;
     0 0 1;
     1 1 0;
     0 0 1];

  %column 1: "1" are at rows {1,3}
  %column 2: "1" are at row {3}
  %column 3: "1" are at rows {1,2,4}

  %Hence, the Cartesian product {1,3}x{3}x{1,2,4} is 
  %{(1,3,1),(1,3,2),(1,3,4),(3,3,1),(3,3,2),(3,3,4)} 

  %I construct B by disposing row-wise each 3-tuple in the Cartesian product

  %c=6

 B=[1 3 1;
    1 3 2;
    1 3 4;
    3 3 1;
    3 3 2;
    3 3 4];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the cartesian product with the `combvec` command, for your example:

```
A=[1 0 1;...
   0 0 1;...
   1 1 0;...
   0 0 1];

[x y]=find(A);

B=combvec(x(y==1).',x(y==2).',x(y==3).').';

% B =
%    1   3   1
%    3   3   1
%    1   3   2
%    3   3   2
%    1   3   4
%    3   3   4
```

---

You can expand this to an unknown number of columns by using the associative property of the product.

```
[x y]=find(A);

u_y=unique(y);

B=x(y==u_y(1)).';

for i=2:length(u_y)
    B=combvec(B, x(y==u_y(i)).');
end

B=B.';
```

Comment: Warning.  `combvec` belongs to the Neural Networks toolbox.

Answer (score 3):

One solution (without toolbox):

```
A=  [1 0 1;
     0 0 1;
     1 1 0;
     0 0 1];



[ii,jj] = find(A)

kk = unique(jj); 

for i = 1:length(kk)
    v{i} = ii(jj==kk(i));
end

t=cell(1,length(kk));
[t{:}]= ndgrid(v{:});

product = []
for i = 1:length(kk)
    product = [product,t{i}(:)];
end
```

Comment: Interesting, I see we have similar codes besides minor differences in indexing and creating matrices.

Answer (score 3):

You can use use [`accumarray`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) to obtain vectors with the row indices of nonzero elements for each column. This works for an **arbitrary number of columns**:

```
[ii, jj] = find(A);
vectors = accumarray(jj, ii, [], @(x){sort(x.')});
```

Then apply [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895335/generate-a-matrix-containing-all-combinations-of-elements-taken-from-n-vectors) to efficiently compute the Cartesian product of those vectors:

```
n = numel(vectors);
B = cell(1,n);
[B{end:-1:1}] = ndgrid(vectors{end:-1:1});
B = cat(n+1, B{:});
B = reshape(B,[],n);
```

In your example, this gives

```
B =
     1     3     1
     1     3     2
     1     3     4
     3     3     1
     3     3     2
     3     3     4
```

Answer (score 2):

In short, I would use `find` to generate the indices needed for the Cartesian product and then use `ndgrid` to perform the Cartesian product of these indices. The code to do so is:

```
clear
close all
clc

A = [1 0 1;
     0 0 1;
     1 1 0;
     0 0 1];

[row,col] = find(A);
[~,ia,~] = unique(col);
n_cols = size(A,2);
indices = cell(n_cols,1);

for ii = 1:n_cols-1
  indices{ii} = row(ia(ii):ia(ii+1)-1);
end
indices{end} = row(ia(end):end);

cp_temp = cell(n_cols,1);
[cp_temp{:}] = ndgrid(indices{:});

cp = NaN(numel(cp_temp{1}),n_cols);
for ii = 1:n_cols
  cp(:,ii) = cp_temp{ii}(:);
end
cp = sortrows(cp);
cp
```