# Cartesian product of row values of a marix in Matlab

Tags: matlab, nan, cartesian-product

Similarly to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38635231/cartesian-product-of-row-indices-in-matlab/48441194), I have a matrix with real values (including `NaN`s) `A` of dimension `mxn` in Matlab. I want to construct a matrix `B` listing row-wise each element of the non-unique Cartesian product of the values contained in `A`s columns which are not `NaN`. To be more clear consider the following example.

Example:

```
  %m=3;
  %n=3;

  A=[2.1 0 NaN;
     69 NaN 1;
     NaN 32.1 NaN];

  %Hence, the Cartesian product {2.1,0}x{69,1}x{32.1} is 
  %{(2.1,69,32.1),(2.1,1,32.1),(0,69,32.1),(0,1,32.1)} 

  %I construct B by disposing row-wise each 3-tuple in the Cartesian product


 B=[2.1 69 32.1;
    2.1 1 32.1;
    0 69 32.1;
    0 1 32.1];
```

Comment: For any `m`, `n`?

Comment: yes, it should work for any 2-D matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with a solution using cells:

```
function B = q48444528(A)
if nargin < 1
A = [2.1   0   NaN;
      69  NaN   1 ;
     NaN  32.1 NaN];
end
% Converting to a cell array of rows:
C = num2cell(A,2);
% Getting rid of NaN values:
C = cellfun(@(x)x(~isnan(x)),C,'UniformOutput',false);
% Finding combinations:
B = combvec(C{:}).';
```

Output:

```
B =

    2.1000   69.0000   32.1000
         0   69.0000   32.1000
    2.1000    1.0000   32.1000
         0    1.0000   32.1000
```

Comment: @Codevan care to elaborate?

Comment: @Codevan *which* other matrices