# Generate vectors and each element in the vector has K possibilities

Tags: matlab, vector, combinations, permutation

I want to generate a set of vectors with length N. Each of the element in the vector has K possibilities (choosing from integers 1 to K).
For example, if N=2 and K=2, the set of vectors are `[0 0], [0 1], [1 0]` and . `[1 1]`. Basically, the number of vectors I want to generate equals to  K^N.

Comment: Is K the same for each entry?

Comment: Yes, the first element is selected from 1 to K. So do the other elements.

Comment: What you want is a Cartesian product. You can use [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21895344/2586922) with input `vectors = repmat({0:K-1}, 1, N);`

Answer (score 0):

I [asked a similar question](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/33346021#33346021) yesterday on the MATLAB chat; I'm not sure what the most efficient way is to adapt it to any general K.

One solution that works, but is inefficient because it keeps resizing `out`:

```
out = [1:K]'
for ii = 2:N
    out = [ repmat(out,K,1) repelem([1:K]', K^(ii-1), 1)];
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a general solution for that (if you have MATLAB 2015a or newer):

```
N = 3;
elem = [6 9 4]; % you can change this to be any vector
K = numel(elem);
out = zeros(K^N,N);
for k = 1:N
    out(:,k) = repmat(repelem(elem,K^(N-k)).',K^(k-1),1);
end
```

so for `N = 2` and `elem = 1:2` you get:

```
out =
     1     1
     1     2
     2     1
     2     2
```

where each row of `out` is one unique combination.

Answer (score 0):

#### First way

This method is based on the fact that these vectors look like base `K` representations of a sequence of numbers:

```
N = 2;
K = 2;
out = zeros(K^N, N);
vec = (0:K^N-1).';
for k = N:-1:1
    out(:,k) = mod(vec, K);
    vec = floor(vec/K);
end
```

With this output:

```
out =

     0     0
     0     1
     1     0
     1     1
```

`out(k,:)` is your `k`'th vector. Note that if you instead prefer to have `[1 1]`, `[1 2]`, ..., you can simply add `1` to `out`:

```
out + 1 =

     1     1
     1     2
     2     1
     2     2
```

#### Second way:

Since [`repelem`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repelem.html) was added in R2015a, if you are on an older version of Matlab, you should use a replacement for it. One of the convenient solutions in terms of readability is [`kron`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/kron.html) function:

```
N = 2;
K = 2;
vec = (0:K-1).';
out = zeros(K^N, N);
for k = 1:N
    out(:, k) = repmat(kron(vec, ones(K^(N-k), 1)), K^(k-1), 1);
end
```

With same `out` as above.