# Matlab: all possible choices/combinations

Tags: matlab

```
     Choice1   Choice2   Choice3
A       1         5         9
B       2         6         10
C       3         7         11
D       4         8         12
```

How can i generate all possible combinations that include one choice for each row in matlab

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/combvec.html this might help

Comment: See if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21895335/2586922) is what you want

Answer (score 0):

Thank you klancar16!

So let's say

```
A = [1, 5, 9]
B = [2, 6,10]
C = [3, 7,11]
D = [4, 8,12]

temp = combvec(A,B)
temp = combvec(temp,C)
final = combvec(temp,D)
```

and "final" contains a row for each possible choice!