# Looping over combinations of several variables for Design Of Experiments in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I need to loop over all the possible combinations of the different elements of a vector between lower and upper bounds.

NUMBEROFVARIABLES stores the total number of variables.

`tlb < t < tub` and `o1b < o < oub`

The elements `t` and `o` can vary in steps of tStep and oStep respectively.

The vector is: `x = [t1, t2, t3, ... tn, o1, o2, o3, ... on]`

For `1 < t < 10`, `1.5 < o < 5`, `tStep = 1`, `oStep = 0.5` and `NUMBEROFVARIABLES = 10` (divided equally/half-half between 't's and 'o's), the generated combination vectors should be something like:

```
x1 = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5]
x2 = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 2.0]
x3 = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 2.5]
.
.
.
xi = [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0]
xii = [1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0]
xiii = [1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0]
.
.
.
xn = [10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0]]
```

How do I loop over each parameter (like in the above example) and store the vectors `xi` in MATLAB?

Comment: I don't know what DOE is, but in newer versions of MATLAB calling a vectorized function you can do `vfun(tlb:tStep:tub, [olb:oStep:oub].');`

Comment: @beaker I have many different 't's and many different 'o's. The number of 't's and 'o's is stored in NUMBEROFVARIABLES

Comment: Then give a representative example of what you need. How are the variables themselves stored? Looping from `1:NUMBEROFVARIABLES` is trivial, so you're probably asking something more. It's not apparent what from your question.

Comment: @beaker Edited the question

Comment: You don't want `xj = [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5]`? You might start looking [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895335/generate-a-matrix-containing-all-combinations-of-elements-taken-from-n-vectors) for ideas.

Comment: @beaker The vector you mentioned is also included. I could not list out everything here. Hence the dots