# How to code 'all combination' in MATLAB?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

`B` is an array. If `B = [1 2 1]`, my expected output is: `[0 0 0], [1 0 0], [1 1 0], [1 1 1], [0 1 1]`, etc and my function is following:

```
function [output] = AllCombination(B)
output = [];
for i = 0:B(1)
    for j = 0:B(2)
        for k = 0:B(3)
            output = [output; [i,j,k]];
        end
    end
end
```

However, `B` can be of any length. What should I do to make that to adapt to any length of `B`?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you can use the approach [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895335/generate-a-matrix-containing-all-combinations-of-elements-taken-from-n-vectors/21895344#21895344) defining `vectors = cell(1,numel(B)); for k=1:numel(B), vectors{k}=1:B(k); end`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function [output] = AllCombination(B)
C = arrayfun(@(x)0:x, B, 'UniformOutput', false);
D = cell(1,numel(B));
[D{:}]=ndgrid(C{:});
output = cell2mat(cellfun(@(x)x(:), D, 'UniformOutput', false));
```

The first line constructs a cell array containing ranges from 0 to each of the elements of `B`. The second creates an empty cell array of the right size to store the outputs of the third line, which passes the ranges from step 1 into `ndgrid`. This constructs all the combinations of the ranges. Finally we apply `cellfun` to convert each into a column vector, and concatenate them with `cell2mat`.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
L = prod(B+1); % length of the resulting array
output = zeros(L,length(B)); % preallocating memory
for ii = 1:length(B) % for each column of the output array
    output(:,ii) = imresize(repmat(0:B(ii),1,prod(B(1:(ii-1))+1)), [1 L], 'nearest')';
end
```

Explanation:

```
repmat(0:B(ii),1,prod(B(1:(ii-1))+1)
```

Repeats the sequence `0:B(ii)` as many times as the product of all elements of B's before it. To take into account that the counting starts from zero we add `+1` to all elements.

```
imresize(...,[1 L], 'nearest')';
```

Scales the vector then to the length of the array

Edit:

Version using `interp1` instead of `imresize` in case you don't have the image processing toolbox:

```
L = prod(B+1); % length of the resulting array
output = zeros(L,length(B)); % preallocating memory
for ii = 1:length(B) % for each column of the output array
    p = prod(B(1:(ii-1))+1);
    output(:,ii) = interp1(1:(((B(ii)+1)*p)), repmat(0:B(ii),1,p), linspace(1, (((B(ii)+1)*p)), L), 'nearest');
end
```

Comment: You _really_ don't need to resort to using Image Processing Toolbox to solve this problem.