# Equivalent Function in Matlab for Tuples for Mathematica?

Tags: matlab, tuples, wolfram-mathematica

Is there an equivalent function for tuples in Matlab as there is for Mathematica?

See the first example:

http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tuples.html

I just mean the outputs and not necessarily the braces.

Thank you.

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21895335/2586922) what you want? It will give a matrix where each row is a tuple. For the first Mathematica example you would use input `clear vectors; vectors(1:3) = {[0 1]}`

Comment: I want to specify a set of inputs, say [1 2 5] and specify how many "buckets" I am interested in, say 2. Then I should get for this example: [1 1], [1 2], [1 5], [2 1], [2 2], [2 5], [5 1], [5 2], [5 5]. It is essentially every combination with repetition of any element.

Comment: You can find the answer here: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7147-permn-v--n--k-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I stated in comments, you only need to adapt [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21895344/2586922). You can do it as follows:

```
function y = tuples(x, n)
y = cell(1,n);
[y{end:-1:1}] = ndgrid(x);
y = cat(n+1, y{:});
y = reshape(y, [], n);
```

This gives a matrix where each row is a tuple. For example:

```
>> tuples([1 2 5], 2)
ans =
     1     1
     1     2
     1     5
     2     1
     2     2
     2     5
     5     1
     5     2
     5     5
```