# Unique columns based on cell array

Tags: matlab, unique, cell-array, cells

Say I have a cell array in the following format:

```
A = {4;[22 16 4]; 23; 51; [16 22]; 32; [4 50]};
```

I want to output the unique *columns* gained by any permutations of the vectors in the rows. 
For example, for the example in the above, the only column vectors that would satisfy this would be
`[4; 22; 23; 51; 16; 32; 50]` and `[4; 16; 23; 51; 22; 32; 50]`.

I can't choose 4 from the second or last rows since 4 is the only option in the first row. Moreover, I can't choose 22 in both the second and fifth rows since this would make the column non-unique. Although empty choices in some rows are not allowed, if there are no unique columns, then I would need to output an empty column.

Does anyone have a smart way of doing this (fairly quickly) in Matlab? Any help would be much appreciated. 
Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a brute-force approach:

1. Generate all possible columns obtained by choosing one element from each vector (Cartesian product). This can be done with [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21895344/2586922).
2. Keep only those columns for which all elements are different. This is easily done with `sort`, `diff`, `all`, and logical indexing.

Code:

```
A = {4; [22 16 4]; 23; 51; [16 22]; 32; [4 50]};  % Data
n = numel(A);                                     % Step 1
c = cell(1,n);
[c{end:-1:1}] = ndgrid(A{:});
c = cat(n+1, c{end:-1:1});
c = reshape(c,[],n).'; % Step 1
result = c(:,all(diff(sort(c,1),[],1),1));        % Step 2
```