# vectorize FOR loop in octave

Tags: vectorization, octave

I'm trying to get rid of the FOR loop and vectorize this if possible.  **The numerical data in the variable data1 will not be sequential data / numbers but random numerical data.**

```
ii=0;
data1=[1,2,3]; %test data will be random data this will not be sequential numbers 
array_joined=[];
for ii = 0:2
  ii+1;
  array_joined=[array_joined; data1(:),repmat(ii,[1,length(data1)])(:)]
endfor
```

Result:

```
1   0
2   0
3   0
1   1
2   1
3   1
1   2
2   2
3   2
```

I'm using Octave 4.4 which is similar to Matlab.

Comment: Probably a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/21895335/2732801  (Did not verify the solutions in octave)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`repmat`](https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/repmat.html) can be used on both `data1` and iteration variable `ii` as follows:

```
data1 = [1,2,3];    ii = 0:2;  %inputs
array_joined = [repmat(data1.',numel(ii),1) repmat(ii,numel(data1),1)(:)];
```