# Matrix of all possible combinations of some indices in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

Consider a Matlab vector `A` of size `1xL`, reporting some strictly positive integers. I want to construct a matrix `T` of size `prod(A,2)xL` reporting all the possible `L`-tuples from `1:1:A(1)`, `1:1:A(2)`, ..., `1:1:A(L)`.

For example, take `L=3` and `A=[2 3 1]`. Then `T` can be constructed as

```
[ca, cb, cc] = ndgrid(1:1:A(1), 1:1:A(2), 1:1:A(3));
T= [ca(:), cb(:), cc(:)];
```

How can I generalise the code above to a generic `L`?

Comment: Your example is unclear to me (perhaps you meant `ndgrid(1:A(1), 1:A(2), 1:A(3))`). Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21895335/2586922) what you want, with `vectors = arrayfun(@(x) {1:x}, A)`?

Comment: Thanks. 1- Yes, that is what I meant. 2- I want almost that, except that the final ordering of the elements does not follow exactly what `ngrid` gives. I checked `combs` obtained with that code and my `T` and I got different matrices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A minor modification of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21895344/2586922) works. The required changes are:

1. Define the vectors to be "combined" based on `A`.
2. Replace `{end:-1:1}` indexing there by `{:}` indexing here, to get the results in reverse lexicographical order.

```
A = [2 3 1];
vectors = arrayfun(@(x) {1:x}, A); % 1. Define input vectors from A
n = numel(vectors);
T = cell(1,n);
[T{:}] = ndgrid(vectors{:}); % 2. Results will be in reverse lexicographical order 
T = cat(n+1, T{:});
T = reshape(T,[],n);
```