# Matrix of all possible combinations of some numbers in MATLAB: how to be general on dimensions

Tags: matlab

Consider a MATLAB cell `U` of size `L x 1`, where each sub-cell is a `G x K` matrix reporting some numbers. I want to construct a cell `T` of size `G x 1`, where each sub-cell `g` is a `K^L x L` matrix reporting all the possible `L`-tuples from `U{1}(g,:)`, `U{2}(g,:)`, ..., `U{L}(g,:)`.
For example, consider

```
L=3;
G=5;
K=4;
%U=cell(L,1);
U{1}=randn(5,4);
U{2}=randn(5,4);
U{3}=randn(5,4);
T=cell(G,1);
for g=1:G
    U1=U{1}(g,:);
    U2=U{2}(g,:);
    U3=U{3}(g,:);
    [ca, cb, cc] = ndgrid(U1, U2, U3);
    T{g} = [ca(:), cb(:), cc(:)]; 
end
```

How can I generalise this code to any `L`?

I think I could use and modify the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62593020/matrix-of-all-possible-combinations-of-some-indices-in-matlab) question but I'm struggling to set the input variables.

Comment: Thanks. I have added what I'm looking for. I though that this question was enough different from the other to be worth it a separate answer.

Comment: I presume you meant `U{1}, U{2}, U{3}` in the loop? Anyway, you can treat `U1, U2, U3` also as a matrix, where `ndgrid` will take it per column (I think, output size is at least correct), so you could simply concatenate all relevant columns from all cells into a matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I slightly adapted the solution of [the other topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62593020/matrix-of-all-possible-combinations-of-some-indices-in-matlab):

```
L=3;
G=5;
K=4;
U=cell(L,1);
U = cellfun(@(x) {randn(G,K)}, U);
T=cell(G,1);
for g=1:G
    Cin = cellfun(@(x) {x(g,:)}, U);
    Cout = cell(L,1);
    [Cout{:}] = ndgrid(Cin{:});
    Cout = cellfun(@(x) {x(:)}, Cout);
    T{g} = [Cout{:}];
end
```

Does that do what you want ?