# Clever way of creating a full factorial sampling from struct fields

Tags: matlab, struct, combinations

I have (for example) this struct array in MATLAB

```
g=struct();
g.var1=[0,1,2];
g.var2=[5,6,7];
g.var3={'a','b','c'};
...
```

I want to create a cell array that samples (meshgrids) all fields one by one

**Wanted a cell array;**

M×N cell array

```
{[0]}    {[5]}    {'a'} 
{[0]}    {[5]}    {'b'} 
{[0]}    {[5]}    {'c'} 
{[1]}    {[5]}    {'a'} 
{[1]}    {[5]}    {'b'} 
{[1]}    {[5]}    {'c'} 
{[2]}    {[5]}    {'a'} 
{[2]}    {[5]}    {'b'} 
{[2]}    {[5]}    {'c'} 
{[0]}    {[6]}    {'a'} 
{[0]}    {[6]}    {'b'} 
{[0]}    {[6]}    {'c'} 
{[1]}    {[6]}    {'a'} 
{[1]}    {[6]}    {'b'} 
{[1]}    {[6]}    {'c'} 
...
...
```

I want my code to work for all general cases, such as an input struct with only 1 field or many fields.

What is a clever way of coding this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use any of the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21895335/3978545) to get all combinations of numeric vectors. I'll define the [top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21895344/3978545) as the function `getIndices` and use the output indices to operate on your generic structure `g`.

The only extra handling you have to have is getting numeric arrays and cell arrays to place nice, I simply added an `isnumeric` check to convert accordingly.

```
flds = fieldnames( g ); % get structure fields
% Get indices of fields (1:n for each field) and get combinations
idx = cellfun( @(fld) 1:numel(g.(fld)), flds, 'uni', 0 );
idx = getIndices( idx );
% Create output
out = cell(size(idx,1),numel(flds));
for ii = 1:numel(flds)
    if isnumeric( g.(flds{ii}) )
        out(:,ii) = num2cell( g.(flds{ii})(idx(:,ii)) );
    else
        out(:,ii) = g.(flds{ii})(idx(:,ii));
    end
end

function combs = getIndices( vectors )
    % Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21895344/3978545
    n = numel(vectors); %// number of vectors
    combs = cell(1,n); %// pre-define to generate comma-separated list
    [combs{end:-1:1}] = ndgrid(vectors{end:-1:1}); %// the reverse order in these two
    %// comma-separated lists is needed to produce the rows of the result matrix in
    %// lexicographical order 
    combs = cat(n+1, combs{:}); %// concat the n n-dim arrays along dimension n+1
    combs = reshape(combs,[],n); %// reshape to obtain desired matrix
end
```